# RecyclerView disappears when objects are added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Whenever I add something (editText or button), the recycler view disappears. The width shrinks. I tried to adjust size for both recycler view and added objects but nothing works. Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


       
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your java code also .So it will be easy to understand the issue

Comment: **The width shrinks.** --> its because you cant add view in between recycleview tags ....you need to make a custom item layout and then inflate in adapter of recycleview...i think you must research about recycleview and how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add TextView in between Recyclerview tag.
If you want add list in your activity then try

layout_activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
     
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
     
    </RelativeLayout>
```

adapter_list_row.xml

```
    xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical">
     
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
     
     
    </RelativeLayout
```

Create myadapter class extends RecyclerView.Adapter Override required methods and inflate adapter_list_row.xlm. In activity need to add this code

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    myAdpater mAdapter = new myAdpater(list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```